# Windows phone 8.1 Emulator launching issue

Tags: emulation, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

While launching the sample application in windows phone 8.1 emulator I am getting this error.

****Error   1   Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
SmartDeviceException - App deployment failed. Please try again.     AccelerometerCS.WindowsPhone**

**Error 2   Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found. App deployment failed. Please try again. 
    AccelerometerCS.WindowsPhone****

Any possible solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem and have found a solution that might work for you as well. Here is what I did:

- close Visual Studio
- open Hyper-V Manager
- delete all Windows Phone Emulator VMs
- in the Virtual Switch Manager (link is located in the navigation bar
  on the right) delete all Windows Phone related virtual switches
- open Visual Studio and try to deploy the application again (Visual
  Studio will create a fresh virtual machine for you)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Really surprised to see that Visual Studio recreated the VM when I went to deploy, and this worked for me. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick search and [Sumesh Thomas's blog](http://sumeshbt.blogspot.com/2014/04/error-dep6100-following-unexpected.html), you might be trying to deploy a Windows Phone 8.1 app to a device with older version of Windows Phone (probably 8.0).
That won't work. Windows Phone apps targeting Windows Phone 8.1 need that version of OS as a minimum requirement.

Also, [another possibility](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/872213/vs-2013-update-2-fails-to-connect-to-wp8-1-emulator) is that there's a pending Windows Update reboot which is causing the issue when deploying to emulator. According to the provided link, getting the latest updates from Windows Update and rebooting your machine might help.

Comment: I am sure that I am running the application on windows phone 8.1 emulator (not on device) and I have tried restarting my machine. Issue still exists.