# Can't deploy window phone apps to Emulator. Error DEP6100 & 6200

Tags: windows-phone-8, connection

I create new default project Window Phone, then run it with Emulator Window Phone but it's not work however emulator started.

I use Window 8.1 64bit with Visual Studio Professional 2013 - Update 4

Error say:

- Error 1 `DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': SmartDeviceException - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`
- Error 2 `DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`

Help me Thanks !

Comment: This is my image about error: http://i1370.photobucket.com/albums/ag272/duynguyena3win/Untitled_zpsee70aebe.png

Comment: I have the same issue, but with a Lumia 930 device.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try all these steps?

- Closing Visual Studio
- Going to the "Control Panel"
- Selecting "Programs and Features"
- Find "Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU" in the list
- Click the "Change" button at the top or right-click and select "Change"
- On the "Visual Studio" window that appears; select "Repair"
- Wait for the process to complete, and re-open Visual Studio
- Run the emulator again

Or else check out for more here:
[Windows phone 8.1 emulator not loading OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061437/)

[Windows phone 8.1 Emulator launching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765745/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error... I'll start by saying that reloading Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Phone SDK 8.0 did not fix my issue. What did correct my issue was creating a blank project within the Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone and deploying the project. Then I went into Visual Studio 2013 and tried deploying my project again and voila, it worked. Why, I have no idea. My guess is there is a file or configuration that is set up by VS Express for WP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It does actually answer his question. He runs the Windows Phone emulator and it starts, however it does not run his application and throws the two errors, DEP 6100 and DEP 6200. Doing what I mentioned fixed this same exact error on my machine and I also have VS 2013 with update 4.

Answer (score 0):

For error DEP6100 on Windows 10 Emulators 10.0.1.0 (1081p 2gb)

You should Delete all (VHD and AVHD) files in:
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.1.0\

All will be recreated when the emulator will restart. Replace MyUserName by you user name.
Should work with other emulators (you could check your local Hyper-V to find the right path)
See you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem and after many attempts resolved it this way:

- Deactivate Hyper-V (and restart computer).
- Go in the Device Manager and open the Network Adapters, here uninstall *everything* with the name "Hyper-V...", this will allow us to reactivate Hyper-V without any conflict.
- Activate Hyper-V (and restart computer).