# Windows Phone 8.1 Device (Lumia 930) and VS2013 debugging works only with disabled WiFi

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, wifi, windows-phone-8.1

There were errors in VS2013 when a Windows Phone 8.1 App is launching for deploy and debug:

> Error 1   Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred
>   during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
>   SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was
>   detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.  AppWP
>
> Error 2   Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot
>   be found. Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected.
>   Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.    AppWP

After performing of many method trying to eliminate this problem (disabling firewall, reinstalling SDKs, updating Lumia 930 to the latest Windows Phone developer preview), I managed to deploy and run an app with debugging. And as topic says, deploying and debugging is possible only with disabled WiFi on the Phone.

After enabling WiFi on the Lumia 930 device while connection of VS-debugger/PowerTools is established, then the debugging session stays connected and working. But if I disconnect Windows Phone Developer Power Tools (8.1) and try to connect again (while WiFi is enabled), it says:

> Power Tools can't communicate with the device. Here's the error message:
>
> 0x80131600 - 0x80131500 - 0xC0000374

Visual Studio can deploy and start a new debug session after enabling of WiFi even after restarting of a VS2013.

But, after restarting the Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) service, VS2013 becomes unable to deploy and debug again until WiFi is disabled again.

That's how it behaves.

**UPDATE**: After updating to Lumia Denim, the bug was fixed.

Comment: What happens when you turn the WiFi on once the debugging has started? Also is it possible to do: disable WiFi, start debug, but in properties set 'Do not launch the app directly', turn WiFi on, start the app along with debugging?

Comment: @Romasz I have updated the question itself to clarify.

Comment: I would test it with another phone on the machine and the phone on another machine to test if problem is specific to this particular phone/machine. I assume you already done that, but just in case, have you tried resetting phone to factory defaults?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it with the following steps:

1. Open Windows Search, search for "services".
2. Find the Service “Windows IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)”.
3. Alter initialization type for automatic and click mouse right button and select Start.
4. Try running !

Comment: This is what helped in my case.

Comment: Helped me too, why is 'IpOverUsbSvc' service going down ?

Answer (score 0):

I put this answer on another post but I guess some did not feel it was an appropriate answer because I didn't find the exact cause - [Can't deploy window phone apps to Emulator. Error DEP6100 & 6200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684092/cant-deploy-window-phone-apps-to-emulator-error-dep6100-6200/28281765#28281765). I see that you are having a few issues that I did not originally have but overall I was having weird symptoms. Below is what I did to remedy the DEP6100 and DEP 6200 errors.

I'll start by saying that reloading Visual Studio 2013 and Windows Phone SDK 8.0 did not fix my issue. What did correct my issue was creating a blank project within the Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone and deploying the project. Then I went into Visual Studio 2013 and tried deploying my project again and voila, it worked. Why, I have no idea but my guess is there is a file or configuration that is set up by VS Express 2012 for WP that has been missed in the VS 2013 with built in WP SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience with VS 2013 where I could not connect the debugger to the device AND the app would crash out with WIFI enabled (emulator was fine)

I solved these problems by installing VS2015 Enterprise RC