# Unable to register Windows phone 8.1 for Developer Account

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

This is really annoying. Microsoft needs to grow up and fix such silly issues.
I already have a developer unlocked device in which I was able to debug until now. All of sudden it started showing device is not unlocked for developer. Now when I am trying to register it is showing iPOverUsbSvc is not running. I restarted the service. Stop and start the service. Phone and system both restarted. Nothing working for me.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753332/windows-phone-8-1-device-lumia-930-and-vs2013-debugging-works-only-with-disabl) but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Since a *lot* of other developers don't have the same problem, I suggest you look for the problem at your side - either your device or your carrier. In countries/carriers that *don't* lock the phones, there is no need for "developer unlocked devices"

Comment: I would also suggest you google for the specific error. The link you posted is irrelevant to the message you received, while *the very first* result for `iPOverUsbSvc is not running` suggests to ... just make sure the service *is* running in your machine

Comment: if you go through the link you will come to know why I visited that link. Any I found the solution. Thanks for your time

Answer (score -2):

Okay finally go the solution. I needed to change the name of device from File explorer and it worked

But the error message we get of no use.

Thanks

Comment: On the contrary, if you [google for it](https://www.google.gr/search?q=iPOverUsbSvc+is+not+running) you will find a lot of information. Did you check that the service *was* running?

Comment: I did check and restarted the service.

Comment: Also note issue was not related to iPOverSVC service. I have already mentioned " I restarted the service. Stop and start the service" which means I have already did all those exercise.

Comment: In this case I suggest you follow the guidelines on how to write a good question, including all relevant information. I'm not the only one that thought this question was ... not properly worded