# Unable to start WP8.1 emulator in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, hyper-v

I recently face a problem when trying to start a WP8.1 emulator/Virtual Device on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise running on Windows 10 Pro. The emulator stays blank for a long time(5-10mins) and then crashes. Error code DEP6100 and DEP6200. Anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try all these steps?

1. Closing Visual Studio
2. Going to the "Control Panel"
3. Selecting "Programs and Features"
4. Find "Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU" in the list
5. Click the "Change" button at the top or right-click and select "Change"
6. On the "Visual Studio" window that appears; select "Repair"
7. Wait for the process to complete, and re-open Visual Studio
8. Run the emulator again
9. Or else check out for more here: [Windows phone 8.1 emulator not loading OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061437/windows-phone-8-1-emulator-not-loading-os) / [Windows phone 8.1 Emulator launching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765745/windows-phone-8-1-emulator-launching-issue)